# Unable to create bean nested exception is :org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working OpenSource project,I am trying to run the war file in tomcat  server. I am getting error:

> Error creating bean with name 'repository' defined in URL
>   [file:/E:/OpenSoa%20Project/openv3/openSOAsrc/repository/web/target/repository-webapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext-jcr.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException: File system
>   initialization failure.: failed to initialize file system: failed to
>   initialize file system

I have pasted content of `applicationContext-jcr.xml` file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="false">

    <!-- Repository -->
    <bean id="repository"
        class="org.springmodules.jcr.jackrabbit.RepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="configuration"
            value="classpath:jackrabbit-repository.xml" />
        <property name="homeDir"
            value="file:${jcr.home}/jackrabbit" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please, add full stack trace and other stuff. Provided information is really not enough.